# How to solve this with SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a query which I have to modify in order to meet some new specifications:

The big picture of the query is below:

[image]

I have a few INNER JOINS which make up the result set of `INNER JOINS`, then that result set is `LEFT JOINED` with `A1` first, then secondly with `SCH`. This is the current state of the query.

Now, what I have to do is add anoter `result set`, `A2` which for the `common part of A1 and A2` (the yellow part), to display the records with the current conditions in the GROUP BY.

My problem is that I still have to display SOME of the records in the blue area (which are common with the initial set, but not common with the new set which I am adding).

I do not know how can I refference those records that are in the blue arrea and FILTER them out (choose those which meet only one condition), without filtering records from `A2`. I do not know what kind of JOIN to use for `A2` (I think I should use `INNER JOIN`, but I am not sure, that is why there is a `?` mark on my diagram).

`FILTER blue -> ALL yellow`

Comment: Picture of query? That's something new in SQL. But we prefer traditional methods: schema, samples, expected results and actual results

Comment: You probably need a left join, but could you show some rows of each one of the 4 tables and the expected result?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo I know what you mean and I agree with you, but unfortunately this is all I can provide. Showing the entire query and all of the other details, which I know in a `traditional` question would help, in this case it would just take me 1 hour to modify (format) the query, half an hour for you to understand the query and for me to explain, and unfortunately this is a bit urgent for me. Please understand and do not hate.

Comment: There's no hate, or even dislike (like downvote) from me. It's just a tip - of how to increase your chances to get help. If it's something complicated, then simplify it till the issue which causes troubles to you - it may be not a real query, but a sample which provides logic in clear simplified example.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you are trying to do all in one single query or even if is it possible. Otherwise I think you should use a query like

```
SELECT your,fields 
FROM (table/subquery)
WHERE keyfield
IS NOT IN (table/subquery)
```

to select the blue part of data

Comment: +1 This is quite a nice summary of how to do it, given the dearth of information provided :-)

Comment: Actually, I doubt. At least because there are two areas on picture while in condition there's only one exception table

Comment: Yes, this is prefferably done in one query, this is my problem. Otherwise I would have done it just like you suggested, with a `UNION` between my original query and yours.

Comment: +1 for avoiding Joins that do not actually get data.

Answer (score 2):

According to your diagram you want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM InnerJoins -- whatever the previous inner joins are
INNER JOIN A1 ON A1.Key = InnerJoins.Key
INNER JOIN SCH ON SCH.Key = InnerJoins.Key
-- Do all inner joins up to here
-- the statement up to here includes the blue and yellow areas only
LEFT OUTER JOIN A2 ON A2.Key = InnerJoins.Key
-- this still includes the blue and yellow areas combined
WHERE A2.Key IS NULL
-- now we are excluding the yellow area as we are asking for the bits where we have no match in A2.
```